# String formatting with Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing bash script which form json file:

```
#!/bin/bash

json_string=$(<product.info.json)
echo "$json_string"

vers=%major_version%.%patch_version%
date=`date +%%Y-%%m-%%d:%%H:%%M:%%S`

echo VERSION: $vers
echo DATE: $date

result_string=$json_string
result_string=${result_string/_DATE_/$date};
result_string=${result_string/_VERSION_/$vers};


echo "$result_string" > "User_Part/product.info.json"

json_string=$(<User_Part/product.info.json)
echo "$json_string
```

it's console out:

```
[14:09:26][Step 4/4] {
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]    "release":{
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]       "version":null
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]    },
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]    "product":{
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]       "group":"CMS",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]       "name":"CMS_prod",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]       "version":"_VERSION_"
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]    },
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]    "application":{
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "name":"OAPI",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "appl_id":"6150",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "version":"_VERSION_",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "date":"_DATE_",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "detail":null,
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "vcs":{
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]             "hash":null,
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]             "branch":null
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          },
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "build":{
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]             "number":null,
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]             "url":null
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          }
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]       }
[14:09:26][Step 4/4] }
[14:09:26][Step 4/4] VERSION: 003.09
[14:09:26][Step 4/4] DATE: 2016-08-23:14:09:26
[14:09:26][Step 4/4] {
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]    "release":{
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]       "version":null
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]    },
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]    "product":{
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]       "group":"CMS",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]       "name":"CMS_prod",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]       "version":"003.09"
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]    },
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]    "application":{
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "name":"OAPI",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "appl_id":"6150",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "version":"_VERSION_",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "date":"2016-08-23:14:09:26",
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "detail":null,
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "vcs":{
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]             "hash":null,
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]             "branch":null
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          },
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          "build":{
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]             "number":null,
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]             "url":null
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]          }
[14:09:26][Step 4/4]       }
[14:09:26][Step 4/4] }
```

*DATE* was set but *VERSION* no, I can't understand why. Please help me with this ambiguity.

Maybe there is more beatiful way to do it, script are executed in build agent server in TeamCity.

Comment: I see `[14:09:26][Step 4/4] VERSION: 003.09`. So what does it mean that VERSION was not set? Also, do you know [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)? It is a tool to parse JSON in shell scripting. It may be way more useful to you than this script you wrote.

Comment: I can't use jq because i can't install it in server. I mean "version":"_VERSION_" in second line. Near to date.

Comment: OK, I see. Try to simplify your example and also provide a [mcve] with the content of `product.info.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are trying to perform the `_VERSION_` substitution twice, and it seems the first substitution is successful, but by default the bash param expansion you are using will only perform the substitution once, try

```
result_string=${result_string//_VERSION_/$vers};
```

this will have the effect of giving the substitution the `g` flag - in regex speak.

Comment: Thanks. I realized the problem. It was '//'.

Comment: glad you got it fixed, whats weird is that to work out my solution I had to replicate your question and just guessed and check that the `//` might make it behave more "greedy" as per other param expansions. the bash manual is not helpful *If pattern begins with /, all matches  of  pattern  are
       replaced  with  string.  Normally  only  the  first  match  is
       replaced.*